Use Like operator to check for one or two digit numbers
How do you use the Like operator to see if a number is a one or two digit number? I can use # or ## but how do I check for numbers that may be between 0-99? The below example does not work:
str = "ab12cd
debug.print str Like "ab[0-99]cd

I am trying to do a more complex Like to check something similar to below where the numbers may be one or two digits:
str = "Local_Buffer.O[3].7"
debug.print str Like "*.O[[][0-99][]].[0-99]

A few of these patterns I'm trying to detect will have multiple 1-2 digit numbers and I'd like to avoid something like below
str = "Local_Buffer.O[3].7"
debug.print str Like "*.O[[]#[]].#" OR str Like "*.O[[]#[]].##" OR str Like "*.O[[]##[]].#" or str Like "*.O[[]##[]].##"


Not 100%, but I don't think like understands numeric ranges, its just characters. Might be overkill if this is the only pattern your matching in your project, but you can use regular expressions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/212869

(txt like "*#*" or txt like "*##*") and not txt like "*###*" should return true for cases where txt contains one or two consecutive digits (but not 3 or more).

For your complex case, the RegExp is a better option. https://regex101.com/r/ZMUSql/1

@NickSlash FYI it does recognize numeric ranges when you do something like below because each number is a character; however this only works for single characters.
If "ab1cd" like "ab[0-9]cd"

I agree with taller about the use of RegExp.
Try something like:
Sub test()
    Dim reg 'As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp 'Assuming corresponding reference has not been activated => use of CreateObject instead
    Dim str As String
    
    Set reg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    reg.Pattern = ".*\.O\[\d{1,2}\]\.\d{1,2}$"
    
    str = "Local_Buffer.O[3].7"
    Debug.Print reg.Test(str)
End Sub

Note: I'm not sure I've correctly understood the expected pattern wrt "[]" so you might have to adjust the pattern in my example.

Thanks, that works! Hadn't heard of that method before so thanks for bringing it to my attention
